# SEMBAST - How to delete particular array from my DB?

Tags: flutter, dart, nosql

This is my sample DB structure stored in my device using SEMBAST.

```
{
  "household": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "group": {
        "group_id": "1",
        "group_name": "UP"
      },
      "states": {
        "state_id": "1",
        "state_name": "UP"
      },
      "cluster": {
        "cluster_id": "1",
        "cluster_name": "Saharanpur"
      },
      "hid": "A02",
      "total_family_members": "5",
      "famil_income": "3400000",
      "bpl": {
        "bpl_id": "1",
        "bpl_name": "Yes"
      },
      "duration": "90",
      "religion": {
        "religion_id": "1",
        "religion_name": "Hindu"
      },
      "residence": {
        "residence_id": "1",
        "residence_type": "Rented"
      },
      "individual_details": [
        {
          "id": "0001",
          "pid": "ASDASD3453456",
          "enu_date": "11-5-2019",
          "personal_details": {
            "name": "Redox",
            "dob": "11-5-1987",
            "age": "32"
          },
          "sex": {
            "sex_id": "1",
            "sex_type": "Female"
          },
          "relationship": {
            "relationship_id": "1",
            "relationship_type": "self"
          },
          "marital": {
            "maritial_id": "1",
            "maritial_type": "Married"
          },
          "occupation": {
            "occupation_id": "1",
            "occupation_type": "Professional"
          },
          "income": "20000",
          "enroll": {
            "enroll_id": "1",
            "enroll_type": "Eligible",
            "specific_reason": "No",
            "other_reason": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "0002",
          "pid": "ASDASD3453456",
          "enu_date": "11-5-2019",
          "personal_details": {
            "name": "Redox",
            "dob": "11-5-1987",
            "age": "32"
          },
          "sex": {
            "sex_id": "1",
            "sex_type": "Female"
          },
          "relationship": {
            "relationship_id": "1",
            "relationship_type": "self"
          },
          "marital": {
            "maritial_id": "1",
            "maritial_type": "Married"
          },
          "occupation": {
            "occupation_id": "1",
            "occupation_type": "Professional"
          },
          "income": "20000",
          "enroll": {
            "enroll_id": "1",
            "enroll_type": "Eligible",
            "specific_reason": "No",
            "other_reason": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the above data, I wish to delete the below array alone, which is the first array value under "individual_details" key.

```
{
                "id":"0001",
                "pid":"ASDASD3453456",
                "enu_date":"11-5-2019",
                "personal_details":{
                "name":"Redox",
                "dob":"11-5-1987",
                "age":"32"
                },
                "sex":{
                  "sex_id":"1",
                  "sex_type":"Female"
                },
                "relationship":{
                  "relationship_id":"1",
                  "relationship_type":"self"
                },
                "marital":{
                  "maritial_id":"1",
                  "maritial_type":"Married"
                },
                "occupation":{
                  "occupation_id":"1",
                  "occupation_type":"Professional"
                },
                "income":"20000",
                "enroll":{
                  "enroll_id":"1",
                  "enroll_type":"Eligible",
                  "specific_reason":"No",
                  "other_reason":""
                }

              },
```

My code in Flutter is below

```
Future deleteHousehold(Household houseHold,int index) async {
    final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.byKey(houseHold.individualDetails[index].id));
    await _householdStore.delete(await _db, finder: finder);
  }
```

I also tried

```
final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.equal("pid",houseHold.individualDetails[index].id));
    await _householdStore.delete(await _db, finder: finder);

final finder = Finder(filter: Filter.equals("id", houseHold.individualDetails[index].id));
```

But I'm unable to delete this particular row. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sembast is a document based database. You can update a single field in a document. So if you want to update an item in an array, you have to update the whole array (but you can only update this array, like in firestore)

I'm not sure what a record is in your example (is 'household' the list of records or a field in your document) but you can easily update/delete a record by key. I have simplify your dataset in a pseudo example below.

```dart
var store = intMapStoreFactory.store('household');

// Add a document
var key = await store.add(db, {
  "residence": {"residence_id": "1", "residence_type": "Rented"},
  "individual_details": [
    {"id": "0001", "pid": "ASDASD3453456"}
  ]
});

// Get its reference
var record = store.record(key);

// Update a single field
await record.put(db, {'individual_details': [{"id": "0002", "pid": "ASDASD3453456"}]}, merge: true);

expect(await record.get(db), {
  'residence': {'residence_id': '1', 'residence_type': 'Rented'},
  'individual_details': [{'id': '0002', 'pid': 'ASDASD3453456'}]
});

// Delete the record
await record.delete(db);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//delete using Finder
final finder = Finder(
    filter: Filter.and(
  [ //you can add more filters
    Filter.equals(userId, 10),
  ],
));
await _chatTable.delete(await _db, finder: finder);


//delete using key
await _ chatTable.record(userId).delete(await _db);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I may, it could also be easier to manipulate objects in dart.

```dart
    final _dbStore = sembast.intMapStoreFactory.store('hokusai_paintings');
    final recordSnapshot = await _dbStore.find(_database);
    final HokusaiPaintsList =
              recordSnapshot.map((e) => HokusaiPainting.fromJson(e.value)).toList();
    HokusaiPaintsList.removeWhere((element) => element.id == data.id);
    await _dbStore.delete(_database);
    await _dbStore.addAll(_database, HokusaiPaintsList.map((h) => h.toJson()).toList());
```